# "Missing semicolon expected" while tying to run a cypress script

Tags: cypress, arrow-functions

I am trying to add `.each` syntax but am getting the error "; missing" or "semicolon expected" also am working on cypress as there is no ;

Test code:

```js
cy.get('.products').find('.product').each($el, index, $list) => { 
  const VegName = $el.find('h4.product-name').text()
  ...
```

Cypress version: ^12.11.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the docs [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each#DOM-Elements), you will see the correct format requires brackets around the parameters for `.each()`

```js
cy.get('ul>li').each(($el, index, $list) => {
```

In fact, that's not specific to Cypress or the `.each()` command, that's just basic javascript syntax when using multiple parameters in an arrow function.

Comment: am already added the brackets around the parameters for .each

Comment: cy.get('.products').find('.product').each($el, index, $list) => {
            const VegName = $el.find('h4.product-name').text()
            if(VegName.includes('Cashows'))
            {
                $el.find('button').click()
            }
        }